VB.NET 2019 - Como ejecutar varios procesos que dependen entre si
Como puedo ejecutar varios procesos que dependen entre si, por ejemplo:
Private sub Backup()
process.start(código...)

End sub
Una vez finalizado "Backup", ejecutar:
Private sub Comprimir()
.... Código

End sub
Una vez finalizado "Comprimir", ejecutar:
Private sub SubirDrive()
.... Código

End sub
Gracias de ante mano

Tienes que asociar un evento para detectar cuando el proceso ha terminado, además debes establecer EnableRaisingEvents en True.
Luego desde ahí puedes ir encadenando el próximo proceso y hacer lo mismo con él
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim process = New Process()

    process.StartInfo.FileName = "proceso.exe"
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    AddHandler process.Exited, AddressOf Process_End
    process.Start()

End Sub
Private Sub Process_End(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("El proceso ha terminado")
End Sub

